# Responsive layout problems on non'standard- widths

Tags: joomla-3.4, module-display, responsive-web-design

I have setup the Maximenu module on this site: www.kingswood.co.uk/camps/

The menu works great on all 'standard' device widths and resizes accordingly, based on the device.

However when the page is resized to any dimensions from 641px (wide) to 720px (wide) neither the mobile or the desktop menu show.

I can't workout how to force the desktop view on the above sizes.

Comment: `502 Bad Gateway`. You sure you've provided the correct URL?

Comment: I think the server had a moment... it's ok now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the **Maximenu CK Mobile** plugin installed, you can change the width at which the responsive menu is shown.

The parameter is called **Limit the resolution for the mobile menu**.

By default, I think it's set to `640px`

Comment: You're welcome ;)